# Why isn't my Android phone responding with USB connection?

Tags: usb, android, phone

I plugged in my USB connector to my computer and the device says it's "installed". I even waited a few minutes to make sure. Then when I tried to open up my media folder from the android phone on the desktop, my computer lags really hard. It does not even respond. I even waited 5 minutes but it won't do anything. I even right clicked properties and it still gave me the same issue.

The USB port is not a problem because I have opened files on a few other USBs successfully without any lag or "not responding". I even went to test my android USB to another computer but it gave me the same problem. I also tested using another person's android usb cable but same problem again.

Is there any reason why Androids keep having the USB connectivity problems?

Comment: It's probably because it does not have the MTP driver. The solution for me was just switch to camera (CTP).

Answer (score 0):

I would be quite beneficial if you could add few details about your phone model/make, and your host, their configurations, and operating system versions/branches. The phone can be configured as a USB mass storage class device, or as MTP (media) device, or as "PTP" device ("picture format"). While your host computer likely has the basic MSC driver, but for MTP and PTP you must be sure that your host computer has these drivers installed. To better understand who is at fault, try (a) to connect your phone to some other known good computer (known to connect successfully to Android phones), (b) connect another known-good MTP phone to your host.

Comment: I found the solution by changing my USB device to CTP (camera) so I was able to send the things over.

Comment: So, you didn't have proper driver for your original device mode. Thus my answer is essentially correct. Could you mark it as such, please?

Answer (score 0):

May be you should check your charging socket of Android phone. Some times it happens that the charging socket only able charge but unable to transfer data. This is same problem with my Android phone. When I connect with PC it's only gets charged and not detected at all.

Comment: The socket and cable is fine. The solution for me was just change my USB settings on the phone to CTP (camera) and I saw my files.